# Iterating over StringDictionary using anonymous type in C#

Tags: c#, collections, anonymous-types

I have stumbled upon a `System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary` and tried to iterate over its entries using `var` keyword like this:

```
StringDictionary sd = new StringDictionary();

sd.Add("key", "value");
foreach(var v in sd)
{
    Console.WriteLine(v.Key);
}
```

I was surprised to discover that this generates a compiler error:

> 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension
>   method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be
>   found

When I use `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` instead of `var`, everything works fine. I can imagine that for some reason when using anonymous type, the compiler is treating the `StringDictionary` as a collection of objects, but I would like to know why. What exactly is happening?

By the way, I do not intent to actually use anonymous type in the `foreach`. I am just wondering about the reason why it does not work the way I thought it would work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `var` is not an anonymous type per se. It is a keyword that directs the compiler to infer the type. I would call `var` an "inferred type" if I had to give it a name. It is often used in situations with anonymous types because you cannot refer to their types by name. However, that is not the situation here.

In this case `StringDictionary`, implements the non-generic `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, which uses `object` for the current item's type. Therefore the inferred type of `v` is `object` which has no property `Key`. Inserting the `DictionaryEntry` for the type causes the compiler to insert a cast. Note that any other type for `v` would actually compile, but would fail at runtime.

As @hvd points out, the awkwardness is just an accident of history. No one has needed to update `StringDictionary` since the generic collection types were introduced so it is now a sort of historical artifact maintained for backwards compatibility. Consider the documentation comments in the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/specialized/stringdictionary.cs,f8c35be19e01efb5):

> Consider this class obsolete - use Dictionary<String, String> instead with a proper StringComparer instance.

Comment: Excelent answer, thank you. I am not using `StringDictionary` in any new code, I just found it in some old code and needed to interact with it.

Comment: @FilipStočes Yea that happens sometimes. I think that using `var` would be recommended most of the time except cases like this. I've seen bugs from invalid casts that could have been avoided by the strict use of `var` for `foreach` loop variables.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary` is a very old class. It already existed in .NET Framework 1, when generics weren't around yet. Because of that, firstly, when it was created, it could only implement the non-generic `IEnumerable` interface that doesn't tell the compiler anything useful, and secondly, when it was created, the `var` keyword didn't exist yet so you had to type `foreach (DictionaryEntry v in sd)` anyway. When .NET 2.0 came around and generics became available, and C# 3 came around and the `var` keyword became available, the class could have been updated to implement the generic interfaces, but there was little point in doing so, since at that point you could just use the generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` instead.

Comment: Oh, I see. So while iterating over generic collections, the compiler is looking on the type T in `IEnumberable<T>` when figuring out the type of entries in the collection. Correct?

Comment: @FilipStočes Yes, but not directly. It's going through the `GetEnumerator()` method, and the `Current` property of the result. `IEnumerable` provides a `GetEnumerator()` method that returns an enumerator which has a property `object Current`. `IEnumerable<T>` provides a `GetEnumerator()` method that returns an enumerator which has a property `T Current`. In theory, the class *could* have provided a `GetEnumerator()` method independent of the interfaces. It wouldn't have been very useful without the `var` keyword though.